# Find string like XXXX - XXXX - XXXX in a file using bash

Tags: bash, file, pattern-matching

Is there any way to find string like XXXX-XXXX-XXXX (where Xs are numbers and letters) in a file using bash?

For example: i have AAAAAAAA-AAA-AAA-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX this string in a text file and i want extract only XXXX-XXXX-XXXX (there are exactly 4 letters/numbers for group rapresented by Xs).

If is not possible to do this using bash, is there any other way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: do you really want spaces surrounding each `-` char? Do you know about `grep`, it is designed to match patterns. You can echo your string to `grep`, or if you have a file, you can `grep 'xxx....' file` and get just the lines that match the pattern. There are 1000s of questions here about grep. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -Eo '\<[[:alnum:]]{4}-[[:alnum:]]{4}-[[:alnum:]]{4}\>' file
```

- `-o` outputs only the matched text
- use word boundary markers `\<` and `\>` to prevent false matches like "12345-1234-12345"

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
grep -E '[0-9a-zA-Z]{4} - [0-9a-zA-Z]{4} - [0-9a-zA-Z]{4}' your.file
```

Comment: I've explained better. The case is very particular because string that i have are in this form AAAAAAAA-AAA-AAA-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX and i want extract only XXXX-XXXX-XXXX (there are exactly 4 letters/numbers for group rapresented by Xs instead the groups before the Xs are random and there is no specified lenght).

Anyway thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

```
[[ AAAAAAAA-AAA-AAA-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX =~ [0-9a-zA-Z]+-[0-9a-zA-Z]+$ ]] &&
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking to find and **extract** the pattern..you can use "sed"

Let say you have the string

> %%$%##$@#$@-&^%-*&*^&-JHU7-iuhY-98Uy-*&$#-

As you mentioned only the groups of XXXXs consist of alphanumeric digits

Command line

```
echo '%%$%##$@#$@-&^%-*&*^&-JHU7-iuhY-98Uy-*&$#-(*&^'|sed 's/[^[:alnum:]-]//g'|sed 's/^-\{1,\}//g'|sed 's/-\{1,\}$//g'
```

Output

```
JHU7-iuhY-98Uy
```